# geoxml3 polygons from kml not clickable

Tags: xml, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, polygon

I just want to use the boundaries of these polys for many calculations. But when clicked the infowindow displays all the attributes which I need and cant remove them from the kml. How could I just remove this clickable function?

//hopefully this isn't a regurgitation..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer in the google maps v3 API group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/5280524a73a27f33#)

They are native google maps API v3 polygons, so you can pass this in 
the options to the geoxml3 parser:

```
polygonOptions: { clickable: false}
```

[see the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference%23PolygonOptions)

(Not tested, but you didn't provide any information to test with)

Comment: Cheers, can't believe I missed that one.